# Calculate the proportion of values every two rows by group in R

Tags: r, dplyr, datatable, data-manipulation

I have this dataset

```
df <- tibble(id, event, duration)
```

I need that the each "dive" row the duration proportion of surface be calculated using the subsequent "surface", and insert the result into a new column. All this separated by "id".

proportion = surface/dive+surface

```
#Output dataframe

# A tibble: 8 x 4
  id    event   duration proportion    
1 A     surface       56 x         
2 A     surface       96 x         
3 A     surface       14 x         
4 A     surface       77 x         
5 B     surface       28 x         
6 B     surface       63 x         
7 B     surface       47 x         
8 B     surface       90 x   

############################################################
```

**Edit:**

In my original data, i have some "dive" without "surface" and this code created is with error.

```
Error in `dplyr::mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `proportion = DurationMin[What ==
  "Surface"]/sum(DurationMin)`.
✖ `proportion` must be size 2 or 1, not 0.
ℹ The error occurred in group 2803: ptt = "2017111870", grp = 1015.
```

Inside an 'id' there will be an odd number of rows, where a "dive" event will not have a "surface" in its sequence. So I need that every time an unpaired event is encountered, it is either ignored or an NA is inserted. It's possible?

Follow this dataframe example:

```
id <- c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B")

event <- c("dive", "surface", "dive", "surface", "dive", "surface", "dive", "surface", "dive", "surface", "dive", "surface", "dive", "surface", "dive")

duration <- c(55, 56, 40, 96, 58, 14, 43, 77, 19, 28, 34, 63, 29, 47, 61)

df <- tibble(id, event, duration)

> df
   id   event duration
1   A    dive       55
2   A surface       56
3   A    dive       40
4   A surface       96
5   A    dive       58
6   A surface       14
7   A    dive       43
8   A surface       77
9   B    dive       19
10  B surface       28
11  B    dive       34
12  B surface       63
13  B    dive       29
14  B surface       47
15  B    dive       61
16  B    dive       45
17  B surface       30
>
```

Comment: In your example, the length of 'id' is 15 whereas 'event' and 'duration' length is 16.  Please do correct it. thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can use `gl` to create the grouping index every 2 rows, and then create the column 'proportion' by dividing the 'duration' where event value is 'surface' (`event == 'surface'`) with the `sum` of 'duration'

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   group_by(id) %>%
   group_by(grp = as.integer(gl(n(), 2, n())), .add = TRUE) %>% 
   mutate(proportion = duration[event == 'surface'][1]/sum(duration)) %>%
   ungroup %>%
   select(-grp)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 16 × 4
   id    event   duration proportion
   <chr> <chr>      <dbl>      <dbl>
 1 A     dive          55      0.505
 2 A     surface       56      0.505
 3 A     dive          40      0.706
 4 A     surface       96      0.706
 5 A     dive          58      0.194
 6 A     surface       14      0.194
 7 A     dive          43      0.642
 8 A     surface       77      0.642
 9 B     dive          19      0.596
10 B     surface       28      0.596
11 B     dive          34      0.649
12 B     surface       63      0.649
13 B     dive          29      0.618
14 B     surface       47      0.618
15 B     dive          61      0.596
16 B     surface       90      0.596
```

---

For the new dataset, we may use

```
df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  group_by(grp = cumsum(event == 'dive'), .add = TRUE) %>% 
  mutate(proportion = duration[event == 'surface'][1]/sum(duration)) %>% 
  ungroup %>%
  select(-grp)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 17 × 4
   id    event   duration proportion
   <chr> <chr>      <int>      <dbl>
 1 A     dive          55      0.505
 2 A     surface       56      0.505
 3 A     dive          40      0.706
 4 A     surface       96      0.706
 5 A     dive          58      0.194
 6 A     surface       14      0.194
 7 A     dive          43      0.642
 8 A     surface       77      0.642
 9 B     dive          19      0.596
10 B     surface       28      0.596
11 B     dive          34      0.649
12 B     surface       63      0.649
13 B     dive          29      0.618
14 B     surface       47      0.618
15 B     dive          61     NA    
16 B     dive          45      0.4  
17 B     surface       30      0.4
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(id = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B"), event = c("dive", 
"surface", "dive", "surface", "dive", "surface", "dive", "surface", 
"dive", "surface", "dive", "surface", "dive", "surface", "dive", 
"dive", "surface"), duration = c(55L, 56L, 40L, 96L, 58L, 14L, 
43L, 77L, 19L, 28L, 34L, 63L, 29L, 47L, 61L, 45L, 30L)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", 
"14", "15", "16", "17"))
```

Comment: Is there a reason you used `group_by` twice?

Comment: @JahiZamy the only reason being that if id length is odd for some, the `gl` on the entire data can have single row for certain ids at the start

Comment: @JahiZamy what i meant is `v1 <- rep(c("A", "B", "C"), c(3, 4, 3));tibble(v1, grp = as.integer(gl(length(v1), 2, length(v1)))) %>% dplyr::count(v1, grp)`

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for the valuable help. Just now I'm using this code in my data. But I'm having problems because he found some "Dive" without "Surface". Would it be possible to insert something in the code for it to ignore these events or add an NA?

Comment: Of course. Thanks

Comment: @akrun I just saw that this way is not ignoring just one row that is unpaired, but ignoring two rows and taking the row that would start the next sequence. Consequently missing all next pairs.

Comment: I edited the dataframe again, but I'll ask another question then as it might be easier. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @CarolinePortal For the edited data.frame also, it seems to  be working fine.  Can you show where it is not correct

Comment: @CarolinePortal i updated the post.  Please check if that works for you